# AEM 6.1 - Unlocking pages issue having resolverFactory.getServiceResourceResolver() approach

Tags: aem, jcr

In a project that I am working in AEM 6.1, we are using the "new" way to obtain a valid ResourceResolver object through the line **resolverFactory.getServiceResourceResolver()**. As you know, is neccessary to have a System User created with the right permissions in the environment, to perform some tasks in the JCR.  We have created a System User with Admin rights.

Attach of the permissions:  [useradmin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMEYy.png)

This user is assigned to the **Apache Sling Service User Mapper Service** config as a **Default User**, so we do not have to pass anytime in the code the Map object with the subservice name. The page path that I am testing is **/content/test/test-1/test-folder/test-unlock-page/**.  Attached the related CODE. When the line page.unlock() is executed this throws a WCMException

```
    @Override
public void unlock(String userId, String pagePath) throws LoginException, WCMException {        

    ResourceResolver resourceResolver =resourceResolverFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(null);
    PageManager pageMgr = resourceResolver.adaptTo(PageManager.class);
    Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
    Page page = pageMgr.getPage(pagePath);

    if(!page.isLocked()) {
        log.info("Page is NOT locked, unlock operation not mandatory: " + pagePath);
    } else {
    log.info("Unlocking page on behalf of: " + userId);
    page.unlock();
}
```

The exception cause is:

```
javax.jcr.lock.LockException: Not an owner of the lock /content/test/test-1/test-folder/test-unlock-page/jcr:content
```

I read the documentation of this [link](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/security/security.html)  and according my understanding when you specify a **modify permission** for this user the user can **lock** (locking) but this paragraph does not tell anything about **unlocking**:

> At the JCR level, users can modify a resource by modifying its properties, **locking**, versioning, nt-modifications, and they have complete write permission on nodes defining a jcr:content child node, for example cq:Page, nt:file, cq:Asset

I am thinking if is possible to assign in other place a permission to unlock to this System user, because it seems that is imposible to do it with the current privileges.

Thanks for any idea about it.

Comment: I have seen this issue. I think only the lock owner and the extremely special `admin` user can unlock. So what you can try is impersonating the lock owner session in your code and then unlock. Let me know if you find another way.

Comment: @Abhishek Thanks for your answer, help me very much.  I tested this and seems that when I create an impersonation in order to let the new system user behave like the admin user, the unlock process works fine! but is weird that if i put a validation before the unlocking with `page.canUnlock()` -- [documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html#canUnlock()) this returns `false` but the unlock process works normally.  It seems to me that maybe for unlocking just the lock owner or explicitly the admin user can unlock. I will tell if I found another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. only the admin user and lock owner can remove the lock.

Comment: the thing that i don't like about this functionality is that they don't allow the `administrators` group to unlock. I don't see any valid reason for this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Just the lock owner can remove the lock. Even a member of an administrators group isn't able to unlock a page. However, the admin user can remove the lock of any page using the CRX Content Explorer.